# Testing an iframe with Selenium puts the iframe into infinite loading while manual check for the same iframe goes fine

Tags: ruby, iframe, selenium-rc

I am testing an iframe within a page. When I run my ruby script with selenium-rc, the page loads up fine but the iframe goes into an infinite loading causing my script to time-out. Though on manually checking the same script, we get the expected result.
Any idea if selenium does something with the browser settings?? I have tried it with FF and IE, both.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by infinite loop? Also are you having selenium interact with the IFrame, or just visit a page with an iframe on it? One idea would be to create a super simple html page, and put an iframe to google.com in it, and see if this problem still persists.

Comment: Infinite means that after some entries in the iframe and few clicks within the iframe, the iframe keeps on loading and never finishes it. Yes, as u can see above, I am interacting with the iframe. Also, this behaviour is observed for only some cases in my test suite.

Comment: I got this one working. Just needed to control the speed of the Selenium run as the speed was too fast for the browser to understand. I used the setSpeed command to do so. Thx for ur comment, it clicked me the solution.